# sql - count with multiple WHERE condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the table width structure like this:

```
record  | color| status
--------------------
record1 | blue | x
record1 | blue | y
record2 | red | x
record3 | yellow  | y
```

I want to count records grouping by 'color' and for each one count 'x' and 'y'. I want to get the results like this:

color=**blue**, quantity=**2**, x=**1**, y=**1**
color=**red**, quantity=**1**, x=**1**, y=**0**
color=**yellow**, quantity=**1**, x=**0**, y=**1**

My query:

```
SELECT color as clr,
       count(record) as cnt
FROM table
WHERE status IN (x, y)
GROUP BY  week(color)
```

I print results in php like this:

```
while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
     echo "color=".$row['clr'].", quantity=".$row['cnt'].", x=".$row['cnt'][0].", y=".$row['cnt'][1];
}
```

So the problem is that my method of printing results in php does not work.

Comment: try to print $row **print_r($row);** and check output ???

Comment: Yes, I tryed the answer of @Arun Krish and that's what I needed, thank you for attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

Query:

```
   SELECT color,
   count(color) as quantity,
   LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(status)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(status), 'x', '')) as 'x',
   LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(status)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(status), 'y', '')) as 'y'
   FROM table 
   WHERE status IN('x','y')
   GROUP BY color
```

PHP:

```
   while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
     echo "color=".$row['color'].", quantity=".$row['quantity'].",x=".$row['x'].", y=".$row['y'];
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I needed!

Comment: This answer seems much too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select color,
       count(*) as quantity,
       sum(status = 'x') as x,
       sum(status = 'y') as y
from t
group by color;
```